# What are some ways to get better at Antichess?

Tags: opening, strategy, chess-variants, losing-chess

I have recently found out about a new chess variant called antichess. I was wondering how to get better at it. Are there any opening moves or strategies in antichess that might help beginners in this chess variant better learn the game? If so, please explain in detail.

Comment: Do a google search, antichess, aka losers chess, has been solved.

Comment: @Herb Wolfe What do you mean it has been 'solved'?

Comment: Just that, it's been solved. e3 is a forced win for white, while about a dozen other first moves lose for white, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Losing_Chess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A strategy that I use when trying to get better at antichess is to open up your bishops. Once you to that, you are able to get your opponent in a pawn trap, making them continuously attack your pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Watch for your opponent’s weaknesses and prevent your pieces from being able to clear through your opponent’s pieces. Opening up your bishops is usually a bad thing, as your opponent can use your bishop to win.

Comment: Welcome to [chess.se]! Stack Exchange works best if we keep all information on the Q&A pages. Please take a moment to read the [tour] and some Help Center articles, e.g. [answer].